# Bone Heat Weighting Error - Spikes

Tags: armature

I haven't come across an issue quite like this. I spent a bunch of time googling around to see why I was having this bone weight error, and I found the following solutions, which I tried and didn't work.

1. Making Manifold - This model is manifold and also doesn't have any intersecting faces.
2. Correct normals - All of the normals are correct
3. duplicate Vertices - Removed duplicate vertices
4. Fix Scale and rotation - Done

I thought it might also be the armature, but I tried armature I've used on other models and even tried this one on other models.

No matter what I do, I just get these spikes and I can't figure out what's going on.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Bone Weight Spikes]

Blender File Here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SvZbrZb7fVsiZeaty9Y8w9GBrc69I_TR?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want to upload files for us to check, please use blend-exchange (30 MB max.) and not dropbox or other random file sharing sites. Your questions and our answers might become useless, once the link to the file breaks. If your file exceeds the file size limit, please try to reduce the size.

Comment: @metaphor_set Is it https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? I tried uploading with a file at 27mb and then 14mb and I just get errors. I'm obviously very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, but I don't quite understand the problem. I needed to decimate the character before the issue resolved itself, so I guess the issue was that I just had too many vertices.